# Wine install - Unmet dependencies Ubuntu 20.04 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 6.0.0~focal-1)

Tags: apt, wine, dependencies

I have a relatively clean install of Ubuntu 20.04.

I have run the lines to include wine focal and i386 + keys etc but I still get unmet dependencies errors.

I could uninstall ubuntu again but I've just got all Jack / pulse and alsa playing nice with ubuntu and simply wish to try and run a few of the Winblows VST's namely the Korg M1 so it's a bit of a pain in the *** to start all over but if needs must...

any help appreciated.

Here's what I have so far.

```
sparky@sparky:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease            
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease  
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]  
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Fetched 109 kB in 1s (126 kB/s)                          
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up-to-date.
```

```
sparky@sparky:~$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 6.0.0~focal-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
sparky@sparky:~$
```

I have then tried to install `wine-stable` which sends me on a rabbit hole for even more unmet dependencies.

Comment: Are you looking for the short overview explanation? Or the detail on exactly which packages conflict? For the latter, you must go down the rabbit-hole. Also, your apt sources seem unusual: two mirrors of the same repo and no focal-updates pocket at all.

Comment: Yeah I thought the hole might be where I was probaly heading with this one :) Instead Ive had a plan..  Rather than a full re-install Im currently tring an Upgrade to Groovy..  This may work and keep settings for my already installed apps..  If not - as im guessing and it will probably throw  a spanner in for my Nvidia and black screen me on reboot as per..  heh - then hey ho I'll try a fresh install back of 20.04 later today and see where we go from there :D

Comment: err..  Wow! Ubuntu restarted with no errors..  All sound / graphics running as they were..  And after "sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable" its now installing from the Groovy repos..  So maybe you were right with the repo issues user535..  Anyway happy days..  Not a method I would reccomend as could throw all-sorts of issues for some but in my case on a relatively fresh install of 20.04..  Yeah..  happy days..

Comment: your issue was likely local, maybe you had disabled updates and or security repos. Just tested here on 20.04, no issue whatsoever, noting that Ubuntu users do not have to enable i386 arch as it's enabled in Ubuntu by default.

Comment: That sounds about right..  I had to edit /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades to show "normal" before i could run the upgrade...  so yeah probably blocked it off in the software manager.. Hopefully this might help someone in future..  Tnx for the replies guys.